# Probability of a pair of dice unordered

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is an easy way to calculate the probability of pair of dice by considered the ordered tuple $$(d_1,d_2) \in \{d_1 \in 1..6 \ \&\  d_2 \in 1..6\}$$

There are $36$ such pairs by the multiplication principle and clearly $6$ of them have $d_1=d_2$.

Now, what if we wanted to calculate this probability unordered? The only thing I can think of is to consider the problem as distributing $2$ indistinguishable balls into $6$ distinguishable bins, which using stars and bars is
$$\binom{7}{2}$$
What possible numerator would make $$\frac{n}{\binom{7}{2}}=\frac{1}{6}$$
It seems like no such numerator exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to calculate the probability of getting a pair of dice with the same outcome by considering all the possible pairings.

Now, there are indeed ${7\choose2}=21$ possible pairs ... However, note that a pair like $(1,3)$ is *twice* as likely as a pair $(3,3)$, and so you can't treat all 21 possible outcomes as equally likely, but that is exactly what you do when you use $7\choose2$ as the denumarator. So that's why there is no nice numerator.

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly why!

Comment: @user2879934 It's funny: I just tried to solve a similar problem by considering all *unordered* pairings, and ran into trouble ... And then realized that treating them as ordered pairs was the way to go!  Glad I could help! :)